# Django Admin: list_display and ImportExport not working Simultaneosly

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a multi-database Django project with Import Export Function for a database update.
If I place @admin.register before ImportExport List_display does not work

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(English,Data1,Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5)

class EnglishAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name","views")
```

if I use this method I'm not having the Import-export function, But I'm able to use the list_display function

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(English,Data1,Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
class EnglishAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name","views")
```

If I use this method I'm not able to use the list_display function, Import export function is working

Is there any way we can Use both Functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `English` model separately

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(Data1,Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(English)
class EnglishAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name","views")
```

If you have some custom login in `ViewAdmin` class then `EnglishAdmin` can inherit from it

Comment: if I register English  (database 0) Separately then Import function won't be applicable to English

Comment: imho import function is available if you inherit your admin class from `ImportExportModelAdmin` so when you inherit `EnglishAdmin` also from `ImportExportModelAdmin` then it should work